# How to solve recursion when using dependent factory methods

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm trying to have all my reference data for unit tests in a single Java-Class. Came up with the following concept. 
The only problem I'm having right now is that I can't call, for example, the booking-Method because I'm having an endless loop with calling the room-Method.

I don't know how to fix this issue.

```
package model;

import com.appenetic.fame.model.Booking;
import com.appenetic.fame.model.Building;
import com.appenetic.fame.model.Floor;
import com.appenetic.fame.model.Inventory;
import com.appenetic.fame.model.InventoryCollection;
import com.appenetic.fame.model.Location;
import com.appenetic.fame.model.LocationCollection;
import com.appenetic.fame.model.Room;
import com.appenetic.fame.model.Tag;
import com.appenetic.fame.model.TimeFrame;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by saschaheld on 30.06.17.
 */

public class ReferenceData {
    public static Room room() { //done
        Room referenceRoom = new Room();
        referenceRoom.setRoomId(100);
        referenceRoom.setRoomIdentifier("Room XXXX");
        referenceRoom.setRoomNumber("Room Number XXX");
        referenceRoom.setDoorPlate("Door Plate XXX");
        referenceRoom.setRoomZone("Room Zone XXX");
        referenceRoom.setBarcode("2345234");
        referenceRoom.setSeats("20 Seats");
        referenceRoom.setStatus(Room.RoomStatus.Available);
        referenceRoom.setFloor(floor());
        referenceRoom.addTimeFrame(timeFrame());
        referenceRoom.addInventory(inventory());
        referenceRoom.setLocationCollection(locationCollection());

        return referenceRoom;
    }

    public static Inventory inventory() { // done
        Inventory referenceInventory = new Inventory();
        referenceInventory.setInventoryId(1);
        referenceInventory.setInventoryIdentifier("0235234");
        referenceInventory.setAssetImagePath("picture.png");
        referenceInventory.setDescriptionShort("Short description");
        referenceInventory.setDescriptionLong("Long description");
        referenceInventory.setManufacturer("Manufacturer");
        referenceInventory.setScanDate(new Date());
        referenceInventory.setStatus(Inventory.INVENTORY_STATUS_NOT_SET);
        referenceInventory.setGpsLat((float)40.2);
        referenceInventory.setGpsLng((float) 10.34);
        referenceInventory.setGpsAccuracy(10);
        referenceInventory.setTagType(Tag.TagType.RFID);
        referenceInventory.setTagValue("XXXXXX");
        referenceInventory.setRoom(room());
        referenceInventory.setInventoryCollection(inventoryCollection());

        return referenceInventory;
    }

    public static InventoryCollection inventoryCollection() { //done
        InventoryCollection inventoryCollection = new InventoryCollection();
        inventoryCollection.setInventoryCollectionId(34);
        inventoryCollection.setCreatedAt(new Date());
        inventoryCollection.addInventory(inventory());

        return inventoryCollection;
    }

    public static TimeFrame timeFrame() { //done
        TimeFrame referenceTimeFrame = new TimeFrame();
        referenceTimeFrame.setTimeFrameId(10);
        referenceTimeFrame.setFrom(new Date());
        referenceTimeFrame.setTo(new Date());
        referenceTimeFrame.setMinutes(10.2);
        referenceTimeFrame.setRoom(room());

        return referenceTimeFrame;
    }

    public static Floor floor() { //done
        Floor referenceFloor = new Floor();
        referenceFloor.setFloorId(99);
        referenceFloor.setFloorIdentifier("Floor XXXX");
        referenceFloor.setName("Top floor");
        referenceFloor.setBuilding(building());
        referenceFloor.addRoom(room());

        return referenceFloor;
    }

    public static Building building() { //done
        Building referenceBuilding = new Building();
        referenceBuilding.setBuildingId(200);
        referenceBuilding.setName("High building");
        referenceBuilding.setBuildingIdentifier("Building identifier XXX");
        referenceBuilding.setLocation(location());
        referenceBuilding.addFloor(floor());

        return referenceBuilding;
    }

    public static Location location() { //done
        Location referenceLocation = new Location();
        referenceLocation.setLocationId(10);
        referenceLocation.setLocationIdentifier("23042134");
        referenceLocation.setName("Reference Location");
        referenceLocation.setLocationCollection(locationCollection());
        referenceLocation.addBuilding(building());

        return referenceLocation;
    }

    public static LocationCollection locationCollection() { //done
        LocationCollection referenceLocationCollection = new LocationCollection();
        referenceLocationCollection.setLocationCollectionId(10);
        referenceLocationCollection.setHashValue("XXX-XXX-XXX");
        referenceLocationCollection.setRoom(room());
        referenceLocationCollection.addLocation(location());

        return referenceLocationCollection;
    }

    public static Booking booking() { //done
        Booking referenceBooking = new Booking();
        referenceBooking.setBookingId(101);
        referenceBooking.setIdentifier("Booking XXX");
        referenceBooking.setBookingNumber("XXXXXX");
        referenceBooking.setTitle("Test booking");
        referenceBooking.setStartDate(new Date());
        referenceBooking.setEndDate(new Date());
        referenceBooking.setAttendees(10);
        referenceBooking.setRemark("Remark XXXX");
        referenceBooking.setCancelled(true);
        referenceBooking.setRoom(room());

        return referenceBooking;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing specific about using static methods here. You've just got unbounded recursion.

Comment: i.e. means "in other words" e.g. means "for example"

Comment: Aside: unless you've got a really good reason to use static methods, don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create the objects first without the recursive references. Then once the objects are created, you can set the values that reference these other objects. So you won't be able to do it in the same factory methods, but later after you use those factory methods to get the objects.

```
public static Room room() { //done
    Room referenceRoom = new Room();
    referenceRoom.setRoomId(100);
    referenceRoom.setRoomIdentifier("Room XXXX");
    referenceRoom.setRoomNumber("Room Number XXX");
    referenceRoom.setDoorPlate("Door Plate XXX");
    referenceRoom.setRoomZone("Room Zone XXX");
    referenceRoom.setBarcode("2345234");
    referenceRoom.setSeats("20 Seats");
    referenceRoom.setStatus(Room.RoomStatus.Available);
    // don't set "foreign keys" yet
    return referenceRoom;
}

// do similar pruning for the other factories

Room room = room();
Location location = location();
room.setLocation(location);
location.setRoom(room);

// create new void methods that wire up the relationships like this
```

What you have is essentially relational data like in an SQL database. Might want to look into how the libraries that translate RDBMS data into objects handle the foreign key references.

Answer (score 2):

As already stated in the comments, your problem isn't due to unit test itself. You just make infinite recursive calls:

`location()` calls `building()` which calls `location()`... (and maybe it is not the only example).

Doesn't the stack trace show where the problem comes from?

As @Novaterata suggested, you should not call your "factory" methods from each other. You should assemble them from outside.